# Changing operation behaviour based on user provided implementation

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I am testing the floating vs fixed point implementation of my algorithm. The algorithm logic is the same in both cases, but with fixed point I check for overflow and resize the results after each step.

At the moment I am doing the following:

```
def mult_float(a,b):
    return a*b #use standard python multiplication
def mult_fixed(a,b):
    #a,b are from a class that simulates fixed points, but lacks of auto rescaling after mul
    r = a*b
    r.resize(reg_size) #losing precision
    assert r.overflow == False
    return r

# in my code... 

def my_great_algorithm(in_vec,f_mul,f_sum):
    
    #[...]
    
    # instead of doing a+c*b
    f_sum(a,f_mul(c,b))

    #[...]
```

And eventually in the test section

```
   
   in_vec_flo = gen_input("float") 

   float_res = my_great_algorithm(in_vec_flo ,float_mul,float_sum)

   in_vec_fix = to_fix(in_vec_flo)

   fixed_res = my_great_algorithm(in_vec_fix ,fixed_mul,fixed_sum)
```

This works. However I was wondering if there was a better, more pythonic approach. How'd you solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like you should be using classes. You can define the `__mul__()` method for the class to overload the `*` operator.

Comment: @Barmar This seems a good idea, and I could also fit the required precision in the class, so that I don't rely on the global variable. I could probably extend the fixed point class I am using by wrapping other operations and create complex numbers.

Comment: You might also want to look at the built-in `Decimal` class.